# how use scroll fixed witin parent.. i want scroll but nexbutton and prevbuton is fixed move .. how use jquery

Tags: jquery, css

i wandted within itemsClass prevbutton and nextbutton are fixed when scroll always center.............................................

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="items">
    <div class="prevbutton button"> prev </div>
    <div class="nextbutton button"> next  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

//css

```
.container{
  border:1px solid green;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:5px 0px;
 }
.items{
   border:1px solid red;
   height:800px;
   position:relative;
   width:500px;
   margin:0 auto;
 }
 .prevbutton,.nextbutton{
top:50%;
cursor:pointer;
position:absolute;
background-color:#FF8000;
font-size:25pt;
   border:1px solid red;
    width:80px;
   text-align:center;
 }
 .prevbutton{left:-88px;}

 .nextbutton{right:-88px;}
```

//jquery

```
 $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
      $('.button').addClass('fixed');
      } else {
      $('.button').removeClass('fixed');
  }
  });
```

i wanted center prediv and nextdiv when scroll within itemClass
[image]

when scroll.. how us jquery

[image]

[image]

i wanted this style and it is always center prev and nex button....
how use jquery and css

see jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/5kE2y/
see example    http://www.waypointarts.com/blog/2013/06/29/fixing-a-side-bar-while-scrolling-until-bottom

Comment: Got a fiddle? Also any code where you've tried?

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/5kE2y/1/

Comment: yes bro. but i wanted  i scroll with prevbutton and nextbutton are scroll down and top.. i want jquery..

Comment: This buttonClass is not position:fixed.. but this position:fixed is within items

Answer (score -1):

```
add this css it works jquery not needed
.prevbutton,.nextbutton{
top:50%;
cursor:pointer;
position:fixed;
background-color:#FF8000;
font-size:25pt;
border:1px solid red;
width:80px;
text-align:center;
 }
.prevbutton{left:0px;}

.nextbutton{right:0px;}
```

Comment: hey ! my friends i wanted jquery scrollTop .. please view photo

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
    $('#scrolltotop').fadeIn(200);
} else {
    $('#scrolltotop').fadeOut(200);
}
});

// Animate the scroll to top
 $('#scrolltotop').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
  })
  });
  </script>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="scrolltotop" style="position:fixed:bottom:0px;right:20px;">scroll top</a>
```

Comment: see this link  http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/5kE2y/  i want prev and next are scrolltop and down but it is limit